# To call an Activity after the text has spoken in the current activity in Android text to speech app

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am new to android. Can any one help me with the following requirement; to call an activity after the speech of the current activity has completed.

The text of activity2 is read after completion of activity1 but activity2 is launched before activity1 text is completed. In this utterance id is also not identified.

The code I have written is follows. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
 public void onInit(int status) {       
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        String text= tt.getText().toString();
        if (text!=null && text.length()>0) {
     Toast.makeText(activity1.this, "Speaking: " + text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
     HashMap<String, String> myHash = new HashMap();

     tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, myHash);
     myHash.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,
    "completed");

     } 
    else if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(Fossils.this,
                "Error occurred while initializing Text-To-Speech engine", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    }

}
public void onUtteranceCompleted(String t) {

    if(t == "completed"){
  Intent i = new Intent(this, activity2.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong order in your code: you need to `put` into the `HashMap` before calling `speak`. Try this:

```
tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
HashMap<String, String> myHash = new HashMap();
myHash.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "completed");
tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, myHash);
```

Comment: i tried out with that approach too,but its not changing its activity1 to activity2. do i need to make ny changes in my onUtteranceCompleted(String t)?